# rewriting localStorage javascript for chrome.local.set

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app

I have this code which is working with the localStorage html5 calls.  However it has to be rewritten for a Chrome Desktop app and I can't figure out how to port it over.

```
window.fakeStorage = {
  _data: {},

  setItem: function (id, val) {
    return this._data[id] = String(val);
  },

  getItem: function (id) {
    return this._data.hasOwnProperty(id) ? this._data[id] : undefined;
  },

  removeItem: function (id) {
    return delete this._data[id];
  },

  clear: function () {
    return this._data = {};
  }
};

function LocalScoreManager() {
  this.key     = "bestScore";

  var supported = this.localStorageSupported();
  this.storage = supported ? window.localStorage : window.fakeStorage;
}

LocalScoreManager.prototype.localStorageSupported = function () {
  var testKey = "test";
  var storage = window.localStorage;

  try {
    storage.setItem(testKey, "1");
    storage.removeItem(testKey);
    return true;
  } catch (error) {
    return false;
  }
};

LocalScoreManager.prototype.get = function () {
  return this.storage.getItem(this.key) || 0;
};

LocalScoreManager.prototype.set = function (score) {
  this.storage.setItem(this.key, score);
};
```

The error I get says "window.localStorage is not available in packaged apps. Use chrome.storage.local instead."

My attempt to rewrite it was this so far.. but it is breaking somewhere along the way.

```
$(document).ready(function() {


$("body").bind('keyup', function() {
      var number = $(".best-container").val();

if(number == 'undefined'){
 var number = "0";
}

    chrome.storage.local.set({'bestScore': number});
});



chrome.storage.local.get('bestScore', function (result) {
     hello= result.bestScore || 0;
    $(".best-container").val(hello);
});



});
```

Answer (score 3):

Porting localStorage to chrome.storage has one important pitfall: chrome.storage methods are asynchronous whereas localStorage access is synchronous.

That means: If you try to get a value from chrome.storage before the callback of the `set` method has been called, the value will still be undefined

Wrong way:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'key': value});
...
chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(items) {
   if(items.key)         // won't be able to find the key
      alert(items.key);
});
```

Correct way:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'key': value}, function() {
   ...
   chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(items) {
      if(items.key)
         alert(items.key); // will be "value"
   });
});
```

or rather:

```
chrome.storage.local.set({'key': value}, function() {
   doFurtherStuff();
});

function doFurtherStuff() {
   ...
   chrome.storage.local.get('key', function(items) {
      if(items.key)
         alert(items.key); // will be "value"
   });
}
```

Comment: Or rather, `chrome.storage.local.set({'key': value}, doFurtherStuff);`